# Why does sklearn and numpy disagree about multiplying component of PCA?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, pca

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

SEED = 123
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=5000, cluster_std=90., random_state=SEED)
pca = PCA(2)
pca.fit(X)
pca1, pca2 = pca.components_

pcaX = pca.transform(X)
pcaXnp = np.array([X @ pca1, X @ pca2]).T
```

And if you print out pcaX and pcaXnp you'll see that they're similar but that they don't agree with each other. Why should these differ? It seems like ".components_" should return what sklearn is going to multiply the matrix by, is there a reason why it's just an approximation of what the multiplication will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCA from sklearn.decomposition uses singular value decomposition, or SVD to obtain your principal components. This works only when the columns have first been [centered by their means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189822/how-does-centering-make-a-difference-in-pca-for-svd-and-eigen-decomposition). If you check the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/decomposition/_pca.py#L112), they do the centering before SVD:

```
def _fit_full(self, X, n_components):
[...]
        # Center data
        self.mean_ = np.mean(X, axis=0)
        X -= self.mean_
```

So to get the PCA scores, you need to center your matrix first:

```
pcaX = pca.transform(X)
Xc = X - X.mean(axis=0)
pcaXnp = np.array([Xc @ pca1, Xc @ pca2]).T

pcaX[:3]
array([[-101.45177987,  212.45583745],
       [ 520.84541298,   87.32254399],
       [-273.26407231, -318.78493994]])

pcaXnp[:3]
array([[-101.45177987,  212.45583745],
       [ 520.84541298,   87.32254399],
       [-273.26407231, -318.78493994]])
```